# Bootstrap tooltip dynamic placement

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm using Bootstrap tooltip through attribute selector. i.e any element has `title` attribute should be rendered as a tooltip:

```
$('[title]').tooltip({placement: 'bottom', trigger: 'hover'});
```

However, for some reasons and for some elements I would like to change the placement. Originally, I did not used `data-placement` attribute for the elements, but for elements that I want its tooltip to have diifirent placement other than the default, I supplied them with `data-placement` attribute and I modified the above code to be like the following:

```
$('[title]').tooltip({placement: (typeof $(this).attr('data-placement') === 'undefined')? 'bottom' : $(this).attr('data-placement'), trigger: 'hover'});
```

This code should set the placement to be `bottom` for elements that has no `data-placement` attribute, while set it equals to its value for elements that has that attribute.

However, the code does not work as expected, it set placement = bottom for every element even,for example, those has `data-placement='right`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `placement`'s callback function receives 2 arguments - the first one is the tooltip argument and the second is the original element.
You can use this element to get the data you are looking for:

```js
$('[title]').tooltip({
  placement: function(t_el, el) {
    return (typeof $(el).data('placement') === 'undefined') ? 'bottom' :  $(el).data('placement');
  }, trigger: 'hover'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div style="margin: 35px 55px;">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">Tooltip on bottom</button>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The function gets 2 arguments as parameters. The first one is the element that being created to display the tooltip (in my example - the `div` container of the black tooltip), this is why I called it `t_el`. The second is the element that we need to create the tooltip for - the `<button>`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because `$(this)` isn't referencing the tooltip, but your parent selector instead, most likely `document`.

Try this:

```
$('[title]').each(function() {
    $(this).tooltip({
        placement: (typeof $(this).attr('data-placement') === 'undefined') ? 'bottom' : $(this).attr('data-placement'),
        trigger: 'hover'
    });
});
```